# Unable to delete Google Cloud Platform Project due to linked to a Dialogflow agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I was trying to delete a GCP Project but the following error keeps popping up.

```
Lien origin
You cannot delete this project because it is linked with a Dialogflow agent. 
Please follow the link to Dialogflow and delete the agent: Redirect Link

Description
Deletion blocked by Dialogflow. Remove lien
```

I deleted the DialogFlow Agent and the redirect link now shows *No Agent* and redirects me to the *getStarted* Page

But GCP still shows the same Lien Origin error.

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As suggested by @yyyyahir, I filed an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162802477 which gave me two options. The second one is the one working for me. First, issue the command `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list --project project_ID`. Note it is `project_ID`, not the project name. For example: not `sany-agent` but `sany-agent-koajku`. Then you should see something like below:

```
NAME                                     ORIGIN                                                                                                                                                                         REASON
p8849062...0d88f4e77c  You cannot delete ... a Dialogflow agent. Please follow the link to Dialogflow and delete the agent: https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/#/agent/63e6667c-...-cbfa0e8cd4d7/  Deletion blocked by Dialogflow.
```

Issue the command `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete p8849062...0d88f4e77c` which should result something like this:

```
Deleted [liens/p88490624627...50d88f4e77c].
```

NOTE: I shorten the UUID.

After that, go ahead and shut down the project. You should able to do that as the lien have been removed.

Comment: Thank you for this! I had deleted the diagflow agent but gcloud web UI would still not allow me to shutdown the project.

Comment: Confirming this allowed me to delete my project when I encountered the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The given answer didn't work for me. Delete command is changed a little bit now. Here is what I did to solve the issue:

1. Open Cloud Shell
2. Run the below command and replace  with the actual project id

   ```
   gcloud config set project project-id
   ```
3. Run the below command to list all liens

   ```
   gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list
   ```
4. Run the below command to delete the lien by entering the desired lien-id which you received in step 3.

   ```
   gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete liens/lien-id
   ```

Answer (score 0):

GCP has a management feature called [liens](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-liens#top_of_page) that protect projects from deletion.

You can check the lien in your project with the following gcloud command:

`gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list`

In your particular case, it might be related to Dialogflow project having more than one owner. This operation requires that [other owners are removed from your project](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-manage#delete).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply
I was the sole owner of the project.
I did delete the DialogFlow Agent from the project and hence it doesn't show any agents
but GCP command you suggested 
`gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list --project project_ID`
still shows an active lien

When i try to redirect to the _Remove Lien_ link 
I get the following message:

**com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project _Project ID_ .**

Comment: How are you deleting the agent? Maybe through an API call or the DialogFlow interface?

Comment: The DialogFlow interface

Comment: This might be related to the platform itself. Try [creating an issue using this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=501190&template=1169471) for the engineering team to take a look.

Comment: I am also in the same situation & nothing above worked for me. Is there anything else from anyone?